# Hash table using open addressing collision resolution

Tags: c++, hashtable, implementation

I am trying to implement a Hash table that takes a string value and stores it in a hash table structure. Every hashed 'slot' in the table *T* needs to point to an index in an Array *A*, the index of *A* stores the string value. (size of *A* is arbitrary) I would like to use a dynamic array for both *T* and *A*, so I can increase the size of both Arrays for an overflow condition.

```
class Lexicon {
   private:
        int N; //number of slots
        int& rN = N; //ref to number of slots
        string key;
    
    public:
        Lexicon (int,string);
        void Create(int rN);
        void Insert(string key);
        //More Functions
};
//Constructor for Lexicon
void Lexicon::Create(int rN) {
        auto hashtable = std::make_unique<int[]>(rN);
        auto A_Array = std::make_unique<char[]>(15*rN);
}
```

I'm not sure if this structure is correct. Can I use hashtable array I created using the Create function in other functions (ie. insert, delete, etc...)? Also, is it possible to keep calling the function Create to increase the size of my arrays, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: _"so I can increase the size of both Arrays"_ This is more complicated than just allocating it on free store. Consider using `std::vector` as a bucket. Assuming the hash value range is 0-255 you will need an array of 256 `std::vector`. See also `std::array`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestion. I'm trying not to use the std::vector class for this, but I will look at the std::array class.